# Need to display data queried from GAE datastore in a nice way

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to display data queried from GAE datastore in a nice way (graphs, etc.)
What is the best way to do it?

As I'm already working with GAE, perhaps there is a google API for that? The only thing I found online is [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) but I need to channel the JS into java which seems complicated.

Any advise will be welcome, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way is to do the charts from the browser not the server. Just pass your data to the js and use google charts to display them. There are tons of examples and a playground for google charts.

Answer (score 0):

GWT is a natural web front end for GAE applications---the Eclipse Google plugin integrates GWT with GAE, and the GWT tutorial includes a section on GAE.  Several charting libraries are available, for example, http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted.  Moreover you can build your own in HTML5 with the GWT Canvas.